# Change a css div or body background image based on current URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html

The reason I need to do this is that the website I'm working on uses the exact same template to display dynamic content for multiple pages. All pages replicate the exact same div id's because they display the content the same way (except for the header content!). The header content shortens however the div id's still remain within the source code.

The blog index page needs to display 1 background image while every other page on the website displays another background image.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code will do what you want:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('somepart_of_the_url') != -1) {
    //Change background to some div
    $('#somediv').css('backgroundImage','url(images/mybackgroundimage.jpg)');
    //Change background to page body
    $("document.body").css('backgroundImage','url(images/mybackgroundimage.jpg)');
}
```

Comment: I attempted to use this: 

<script language="javascript"> 
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/cloud/') != -1) {
    //Change background
    $('#body_wrap_3').css('backgroundImage','url(images/headerbg2.jpg)!important');
}
</script>

which did not work.

Comment: Does $('#body_wrap_3') match something, that is, is alert($('#body_wrap_3').length) show a value greater than zero ?

Comment: Also, does it work if you remove the !important ? do you need it?

Comment: I removed important and also tried multiple ways of formatting the URL without any luck. #body_wrap_3 is the div containing headerbg.jpg while #body contains my footer image. When not on the home page, I'd like it to change to headerbg2.jpg.

Comment: Is the path to your image (images/headerbg2.jpg) right? I mean headerbg2.jpg is inside a directory called images and this directory is at the same level that your html page ?

Comment: Actually no, I had also modified that to be /images/headerbg2.jpg because my header is at the root/images/. Sorry for not communicating this.

Answer (score 1):

I often give the body class a name based on the template or request path. I know you said that they all use the same template, but that template takes params and one of the params should be

```
body_class
```

And whatever controller/dynamic thing you have populating your site and rendering the template, should pass in 'home' when you're at /. In my previous experience, I would pass in other things as well so that /blog/category/post might have a body class like

```
<body class="post two-column-a">
```

Then your selectors are something like:

```
body { ... }
body.home { ... }
```

Comment: Unfortunately from what I can see all of the classes and div's are used across the board in multiple pages. Anything on index.html is also on archiveindex.html

Comment: Assuming that you have access to the thing generating the pages from the templates, you ought to be able to change the parameters input into the templates. Your only other option is one of the JavaScript solutions -- they're a kludge. At my places of employment, this has caused a flicker of the old background before the new one is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if (window.location.href.indexOf('INDEX_URL') != -1) {
//Change background
$('#DIV_ID').css({'background-image': 'url(http://URL.com/images/BG.jpg)', 'background-repeat': 'repeat-x', 'background-position': 'center top', 'width': '100%!important', 'min-height': '400px'});
}
});
</script>
```

The flaw that this code has though is that if you insert a directory into "INDEX_URL" such as /folder/, any page after /folder/ will have that background.

Comment: can also use "$(function() {" which doesn't wait for the page to load first.